# What do you call a function from symbols of alphabet to languages?

Tags: formal-languages, terminology, strings

Speaking of context-free (and maybe regular? or just any?) languages, what do you call a function defined as follows:

Let $\Sigma$ be the alphabet of $L$, $\forall \sigma \in \Sigma: f(\sigma) = L'$, where $L'$ is some language. I also met this definition: $f:\Sigma \to 2^{\Delta^*}$.

The reason I'm asking this is because I study in a language which is even more foreign to me than English, and it's hard to find what the terminology in the book means. I've only encountered this in connection to context-free languages, but since I don't really know what I'm looking at, I can't tell if that's something specific to them (my guess though is that it's not).

---

In the book I'm reading from, (which also happens to be in Hebrew) the word used to describe this concept is "הצבה", literally meaning "substitution" or "positioning", "fixing something in place".

Comment: What is $L$ and why is it relevant. I mean, can't you just say "Let $\Sigma$ be an alphabet, $\forall \sigma \in \Sigma : $ (...) "  ?

Comment: $L$ is some language. It is only relevant insofar as to give the reader the general idea of what the alphabet is used for, but it has no bearings on the meaning of the formula. At least not that I can see how it would. Regardless, I just copied more context around the formula in hopes to make it easier to answer the question.

Comment: I think $2^{\Delta^*}$ is supposed the represent an uncountable set. The set of all possible languages over an alphabet $\Sigma$ is indeed an uncountable set. If what I think is correct, another notation for $2^{\Delta^*}$ is $\mathbb{P}(\Sigma)$. I'm not sure because I'm used to $2^{\aleph_0}$ for uncountable sets. Don't be confused though because since $\Sigma$ is a countable set, $Im(f)$ is countable as well, despite the co-domain of $f$ is uncountable.

Comment: It doesn't have any particular name. It's just a function mapping symbols to languages.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus well, it does in the book I'm reading from, this is why I asked. If it matters, the book calls this "הצבה", which literally translates into something like "substitution" or "positioning", in the sense as "making something stand in some place, possibly by force".

Comment: The proper translation is *substitution*, but substitution is a general name, and doesn't always refer to a function mapping symbols to languages.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus well, since I happen to know you can read Hebrew, I just want to confirm this is the right term (I would be very grateful if you could point me to information in English discussing the same thing): see page 14 in http://webcourse.cs.technion.ac.il/236353/Spring2010/ho/WCFiles/Lecture9-1pp.pdf presentation. It seems to be talking about some very specific kind it calls "context-free substitution", which also has some very specific properties (such as closure under this operation).

Comment: @wvxvw It probably means that all languages in the range are context-free.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus that's actually not the case. :) In the assignment I need to decipher the languages in the range are context-sensitive. Although I managed to found something that looks like it may be it: http://infolab.stanford.edu/~ullman/ialc/slides/slides10.pdf my last problem with interpreting $f(L)$ as a language is whether to rename the terminals or not. Though it probably doesn't matter for the question I need to answer. For the specific question I need to answer: https://github.com/wvxvw/intro-to-automata-theory/blob/master/syllabus.pdf page 15.

Comment: See also [Wikipedia on string homomorphisms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_homomorphism). (Please add the tidbit about the Hebrew term and its literal translation to the question -- it might have been instrumental for finding the answer!)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like it refers to a *substitution*, but that the given definition is incomplete.

Anyway, in formal language theory, people often use monoid morphisms between free monoids. To avoid overloading the term "morphism", a monoid morphism from a free monoid $A^*$ into the monoid $2^{B^*}$ of languages of $B^*$ (under concatenation product of languages) is often called a *substitution*.

Now, since a morphism from $A^*$ into any monoid is entirely defined by the image of its letters, a substitution from $A^*$ to $B^*$ might be given as a map $\sigma: A \to 2^{B^*}$. But then it is extended to a map $A^* \to 2^{B^*}$ by setting $\sigma(1) = \{1\}$ and $\sigma(a_1 \dotsm a_n) = \sigma(a_1) \dotsm \sigma(a_1)$.

**Reference**. Page 5 in [First four chapters](http://www.infop7.org/file/659/LivreTransductions14dec2009.pdf) of
Berstel's book Transductions and Context-Free Languages, Teubner (1979).
(Page 13 in the printed version)

Comment: Just to make sure, $1$ is the identity under concatenation, i.e. if talking about strings, that would be the empty string, am I right?

Comment: Exactly. So for $A^*$ the identity is the empty word, and for $2^{B^*}$, the identity is the language $\{1\}$ containing only one word, the empty word.